# Creating an Array from a JSON Collection of Collections using VBA

Tags: arrays, json, excel, vba

I am importing json data using an API call. Some of the data ("columns" and "values") are collections and collections of collections, respectively. With these collections, I am then trying to create an array and then paste the array into an excel sheet.  I have been successful in getting the "columns" data pasted into the sheet using the following code:

```
Dim ColumnArray as Variant

ColumnArray = CollectionToArray(sensorData_json("columns"))
ws31.Range("F8:I8").Value = ColumnArray

Public Function CollectionToArray(myCol As Collection) As Variant

    Dim result  As Variant
    Dim cnt     As Long

    ReDim result(myCol.Count)
    For cnt = 0 To myCol.Count - 1
        result(cnt) = myCol(cnt + 1)
    Next cnt
    CollectionToArray = result

End Function
```

However, I haven't had success with the "values" data.  I believe the challenge is that "values" is a collection of collections which causes my error.  I have primarily been getting Run-time error '450' and Run-time error '13' errors.  Below is an example of the JSON data:

```json
{
    "project_pk": "xxxxxxx",
    "project_name": "ABCDE",
    "columns": ["A", "B", "C"],
    "values": [
        ["2020-02-05T00:00:00Z", 1.111, 2.222],
        ["2020-02-05T00:00:10Z", 3.333, 4.444],
        ["2020-02-05T00:00:20Z", 5.555, 6.666]...
```

Updated code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetSensorData()

    Dim objRequest As Object
    Dim strUrl As String
    Dim blnAsync As Boolean
    Dim strResponse As String
    Dim ws31 As Worksheet
    
    Set ws31 = Sheet31
    
    'clear previous information from sheet
    
    ws31.Range("B8:C9").ClearContents
    ws31.Range("B15:I10000").ClearContents
    
    Set objRequest = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    strUrl = "https://binni.azure-api.net/tunneling/project/" & ws31.[ProjectID5] & "/tbm/" & ws31.[TBMID5] & "/getTbmSensorData?tbmSensorIds=" & [TBMSensorsIDs] & "?fromDateTime=" & [fromDateTime] & "?toDateTime=" & [toDateTime]
        blnAsync = False

    With objRequest
        .Open "GET", strUrl, blnAsync
        .SetRequestHeader "Subscription-Key", ws31.[D2]
        .Send
    
    End With
    
    strResponse = objRequest.ResponseText

    Dim sensorData_json As Dictionary
    Set sensorData_json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(strResponse)
    
    'Get Project and TBM Name and place into worksheet
    
    ws31.Cells(8, 2) = sensorData_json("project_name")
    ws31.Cells(9, 2) = sensorData_json("tbm_name")
       
    'Get sensor information
        
    Dim JsonObject As Object, Arr

    Set JsonObject = JsonConverter.ParseJson(strResponse)
    
    Arr = GetArray(JsonObject)
    
    ws31.Range("A12").Resize(UBound(Arr, 1), UBound(Arr, 2)).Value = Arr
    
    
End Sub


Function GetArray(obj As Object)
    Dim Arr, headers, values, n As Long, i As Long, v
    
    Set headers = obj("columns")
    Set values = obj("values")
    'resize output array based on collection sizes
    ReDim Arr(1 To values.Count + 1)
    
    For n = 1 To headers.Count 'loop the headers
        Arr(1, n) = headers(n)
    Next n
    i = 2
    For Each v In values      'for each value collection
        For n = 1 To v.Count  '  loop the individual values
            Arr(i, n) = v(n)
        Next n
        i = i + 1
    Next v
    GetArray = Arr
End Function
```

Comment: Suggest you use either `Power Query` or [Tim Hall's JSON converter for VBA](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON)

Comment: You can pass the top-level object to your function - size the output array to 1 to [number of columns], 1 to [number of "values" + 1]  Fill the first "row" of the array from the `columns` collection, then fill each subsequent row from the `values` collection.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data represents a regular table (same # of items in each row):

```vb
Sub Test35()

    Dim JsonObject As Object, arr

    'loading from a cell for testing...
    Set JsonObject = JsonConverter.ParseJson(Sheet2.Range("A15").Value)
    
    arr = GetArray(JsonObject)
    
    Sheet2.Range("C17").Resize(UBound(arr, 1), UBound(arr, 2)).Value = arr

End Sub

Function GetArray(obj As Object)
    Dim arr, headers, values, n As Long, i As Long, v
    
    Set headers = obj("columns")
    Set values = obj("values")
    'resize output array based on collection sizes
    ReDim arr(1 To values.Count + 1, 1 To headers.Count)
    
    For n = 1 To headers.Count 'loop the headers
        arr(1, n) = headers(n)
    Next n
    i = 2
    For Each v In values      'for each value collection
        For n = 1 To v.Count  '  loop the individual values
            arr(i, n) = v(n)
        Next n
        i = i + 1
    Next v
    GetArray = arr
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks Tim!  I have adapted and tried the code you suggested but keep running into similar issues, this time it is a Run time error 9 that I can't seem to get past.  The error occurs in the line  "Arr(1, n) = headers(n)" however during debugging I can see that the JSON data has been passed to the headers variable.   I have added the entire updated code to my original post.  Any additional suggestions is much appreciated.

Comment: I can't really test your code without access to the full response, but one thing that stands out is you've changed the output array dimensions to a 1-D array - that won't work if you want to return the full table.

Comment: Ah yes, I accidentally cut the 2nd dimension out of the array.  I have added it back in and the code works great!  Thanks again for your help!